# input type number on Firefox: click on spin button not fire focus event

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

On Chrome when users click on the spin button of the input number the focus event is fired, but not on Firefox. How fire the focus on Firefox like Chrome?

**FIREFOX**

[image]

**CHROME**

[image]

**LIVE DEMO**

```js
function onFocus(){
  console.log('focused');
}
```

```html
<input type="number" onfocus="onFocus()">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add onChange listener, inside trigger focus for input.  `event.target.focus()`

Comment: yep... but stackoverflow require to wait some minutes before accept